# How to override django.utils.text.slugify function

Tags: django

Because slugify function of Django is not suitable for me. So, I would like to override this function.

There is any way to do that? Please give me any suggestion or ideas.

Thank you so much

Comment: inspect the source, create your function and use wherever you want to.

Comment: I deploy the source to Heroku. So, I think this is not the solution

Answer (score 1):

how about using existing one like
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/690/

Comment: Thanks soField, but this is not the thing that I want